# Error while awk division fatal: division by zero attempted

Tags: shell, awk

i have a input  file like below:

```
OC OPC 0 0 0 -202001
OC OPC 0 0 0 -201812
OC OPK 27 11 28 -60
OC OIP 0 48344 0 -153058
```

i tried to take percentage by doing `awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$5*100/$3,$4,$6*100/$4}'`

got below error fatal: division by zero attempted

there are valid 0 in my data.

Comment: What's the expected outcome though? AFAIK x/0 is undefined

Answer (score 2):

You are getting these errors because in code there are values which are getting divided by zero(0), to avoid that you could use following.

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$3!=0?$5*100/$3:"NaN",$4,$4!=0?$6*100/$4:"NaN"}' Input_file
```

Where `NaN` is the value which will let us know that value was getting divided by zero so to avoid that its  printing `NaN` there.

I am checking condition here with help of operators `?` and `:`, if field(3rd  or 4th, since OP is dividing with those values only) is zero then simply print `NaN` or do the divide.